# Use of unresolved identifier 'Static'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have updated xcode 8.0 swift 3 and I found many errors. This is one of them :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Static'

This is my class that i created and worked in previous version xcode 7.3.1 swift 2.

```
import UIKit

enum FONTSIZE:Int
{
    case sizesmall = 1
    case sizesbig = 2
    case sizemedium = 3
}

class sizeFont: NSObject {

    private static var __once: () = {
            Static.instance = sizeFont()
        }()

    class func getSize(_ enumFont : FONTSIZE) -> CGFloat {
        var siz = 17
        switch(enumFont){
        case .sizesbig:
            if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 0){// kecil
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 22//17
                }else{
                    siz = 22//24
                }

            }else if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 1){// besar
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 30//19
                }else{
                    siz = 30//28
                }
            }else{
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 22//17
                }else{
                    siz = 22//22
                }
            }

            break
        case .sizesmall:
            if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 0){// kecil
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 17//15//12
                }else{
                    siz = 24//22//19
                }
            }else if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 1){// besar
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 19//17//15
                }else{
                    siz = 28//26//24
                }
            }else{
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 17//15//12
                }else{
                    siz = 24//22//19
                }
            }
            break
        case .sizemedium:
            if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 0){// kecil
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 15
                }else{
                    siz = 22
                }
            }else if((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fontsize") as AnyObject).int32Value == 1){// besar
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 17
                }else{
                    siz = 26
                }
            }else{
                if(isphone()){
                    siz = 15
                }else{
                    siz = 22
                }
            }
            break
        }
        return CGFloat(siz)
    }

    func getnametag(){

    }

    class func isphone() ->Bool {
        if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone){
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }

    // example singleton swift
    class var sharedInstance: sizeFont {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: Int = 0
            static var instance: sizeFont? = nil
        }
        _ = sizeFont.__once
        return Static.instance!
    }


}
```

The red line code is Static.instance = sizeFont().

I am not sure why I am getting this, does anyone else know ?

Comment: Static is a reserved keyword for Swift. Please change it to some other name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Static` is declared inside class variable, that cause unreachability to everybody outside var declaration, just move it to outside.

```
...
struct Static {
    static var onceToken: Int = 0
    static var instance: sizeFont? = nil
}
// example singleton swift
class var sharedInstance: sizeFont {
    _ = sizeFont.__once
    return Static.instance!
}
...
```